# Is there a way way to use the Address book from an app?

Tags: ios, addressbook, phone-call

Is it possible to pop the address book with users contacts in an app?

I want to let the user dial to his contacts from my app.

I wanted to do this with URL SCHEME CALL but I don't want a specific contact, I want the user to choose who to dial to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` class to allow user to choose a contact from his address book. When contact is selected  the `peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:` method in picker's delegate is called (see [ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol reference for more methods available) and you can dial selected contact in that method as you wanted.